# Managing uploaded files in Laravel - linking public and storage directories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.1 app, I'm storing images in **storage/app/uploads** folder.

My `local` disk:

```
<?php

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app/uploads'),
    ],
    // other configuration...

?>
```

Thing is, I can't figure out a way to use the image files after they're uploaded, e.g. as the source of `<img>` tag. Basically, I need to retrieve a valid path to an image, so it can be used on the page.

For deployment I'm using Envoyer which provides a solution. According to [Envoyer docs](https://envoyer.io/docs):

> When storing user uploaded files, **you should store them in the storage directory** of your application if you are using Laravel. Then, you may use the "Manage Linked Folders" feature of Envoyer to create a **symbolic link** from your public directory to the storage directory. The "Manage Linked Folders" button can be found on the "Deployment Hooks" tab of your project.

..and this is clear.

But how do I "link" the **storage** and **public** folders in my local development environment? Does Laravel provide a way to do it, or do I need to create a symbolic link in my environment manually?

Comment: Yes, you'd create a symlink yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Create a controller that would output the files

   ```
   class AssetController {
     public function show($id) {
       $file = File::findOrFail($id);
       return Response::make(Storage::get($file->storage_key), 200, ['Content-Type' => $file->mime_type]);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create a symlink **public/assets => storage/app/**
3. Upload files to **public/assets** instead of **storage/app**
4. Use rewrites on your web server to serve the files from your **storage/app** folder - how to do that depends on what webserver you are using. For **nginx** you could use something like

   ```
   rewrite ^/v1/assets/(\d+) /../storage/app/$1;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for these. I actually would stick to option (2), so the symlink creation. Thing is I've stored the images in **public** and used `asset()` to retrieve the paths to files. However, in many places **storage** is mentioned as the "right" place to keep user uploads, hence the refactoring I'm doing now. But honestly, I'm not sure what is the real advantage of this solution.

Comment: The advantage of storing files in storage/ is that you have greater control over them. Things that are in public/ can be accessed by anyone. Things that are in storage/ are ony accessible to Laravel, so it allows you to limit access to them only to authenticated users or owners of the files.

Comment: Does this mean the images stored in **storage** won't be directly available when accessed from the browser bar? I mean, if I'm creating a symlink anyway, doesn't it make the files equally accessible by anyone?

Comment: It depends on your web server config, but by default only things in public should be accessible, unless you grant server rights to access storage and symlink that or implement a controller that would serve files to the users

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much.